# How to display all items with key value name in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I want to  display the following array list with *key-names* and *key-values* using loop in tabular form instead of  *foreach* loop. (as already used)

```
$marks = array(
    "Rahul" => array("Java" => "80", "Algorithms" => "72", "DBMS" => "88"),
    "Anita" => array("Java" => "90", "Algorithms" => "84", "DBMS" => "88"),
);

/**
 * I want to use *for loop* to display
 * all items with key(index values)and data items
 */
foreach ($marks as $new)
{
    echo $new['Java'] . " " . $new['Algorithms'] . " " . $new['DBMS'] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Simply [check the manual on `foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: So you don't know how to access `Rahul` and `Anita`? @IMP

Comment: How dynamic does this need to be?  What is your exact desired output? @IMP  Why do you seem to have some bias against a `foreach()` loop -- this part makes not sense to me?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand it correctly,

```
foreach ($marks as $new => $n)
{ 

    echo $new." - Java : ".$n['Java'].", Algorithms : ".$n['Algorithms'].", DMBS: ".$n['DBMS']."\n <br>";  
}
```

[image: Code Review]

Answer (score 0):

All in for loop

```
<?php
$marks = array (

    "Rahul" => array ("Java" => "80", "Algorithms" => "72","DBMS" => "88"),

    "Anita" => array ("Java" => "90", "Algorithms" => "84","DBMS" => "88"),
);

// Get all user names
$arrayNames = array_keys($marks);
$x = true;
$sizeMarks = sizeof($marks);
for($i=0; $i< $sizeMarks; $i++){
    

    $nameKey = $arrayNames[$i];
    $subsArray = $marks[$nameKey];

    if($x == true){
        $sizeSubjects = sizeof($subjects);
        $x = false;
    }

    $subjects = array_keys($subsArray);
    for($j=0; $j< $sizeSubjects; $j++){

        $subjectKey = $subjects[$j];
        echo $nameKey ." ".$subjects[$j]." ".  $marks[$nameKey][$subjectKey]."\n"; 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: True. I just wanted to write an answer using all for loop.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your input array has a predictable structure.  You can use a single `foreach()` to access the first level keys as well as the full second level data by assigning each associative value to a variable.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/t9rQV))

```
$marks = [
    "Rahul" => ["Java" => "80", "Algorithms" => "72","DBMS" => "88"],
    "Anita" => ["Java" => "90", "Algorithms" => "84","DBMS" => "88"],
];

foreach ($marks as $key => ['Java' => $java, 'Algorithms' => $algo, 'DBMS' => $dbms]) {
    echo "$key : Java => $java, Algorithms => $algo, DBMS => $dbms\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Rahul : Java => 80, Algorithms => 72, DBMS => 88
Anita : Java => 90, Algorithms => 84, DBMS => 88
```

Answer (score -1):

Since the user is interested in key  , first foreach gets the key ($ind) “Rahul” then loop on the array and echo subsequent key ($ind2) “Java”, “Algorithms”, “DBMS” and their values($val) , same thing happens with key “Anita”

```
 $marks = array(
        "Rahul" => array("Java" => "80", "Algorithms" => "72", "DBMS" => "88"),
        "Anita" => array("Java" => "90", "Algorithms" => "84", "DBMS" => "88"),
    );
    
    foreach ($marks as $ind => $new) {
        foreach ($new as $ind2 => $val) {
            echo $ind . " " . $ind2 . '-' . $val . "\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you explain your answer

Comment: explained the answer